# Slide Toggle Won't Activate On Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I looked up many questions on this topic and there are similar answers that should work, but it's not working for me. I admit DOM traversal is not my strong point, so if you have a solution and can give some context it would really help me understand why the other solutions weren't working.

I have a div with a button and on a button click (this button only appears on mobile) it should slide down only the current div content. I can get this to work, but the issue is it opens up ALL the divs content. I cannot however get it to only open the specific card even using solutions such as $(this), $(next), $(prev) or $(find).

The code I am posting below does not open it at all, and I am using this version of the code because it is most similar to answers on Stack Overflow.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.mobile-icon').on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().find('.card-bottom').slideToggle();
  console.log('hi there'); //this does print

 });


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- FIRST CARD -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-top">
     <h1 class="card-title">Headline</h1>
  <a href="#" class="mobile-icon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END CARD-TOP -->
    
       <div class="card-bottom">
      <p>Content to be toggled</p>
    </div>
       <!-- END CARD BOTTOM -->
    </div>
    <!-- END CARD -->

    <!-- SECOND CARD -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-top">
     <h1 class="card-title">Headline</h1>
  <a href="#" class="mobile-icon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END CARD-TOP -->
    
       <div class="card-bottom">
      <p>Content to be toggled</p>
    </div>
       <!-- END CARD BOTTOM -->
    </div>
    <!-- END CARD -->
```

Comment: You need to pass `event` into your function to use preventDefault().  Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: This was a error on my behalf as I was copying code I was undoing some changes to pull up the code I wanted to use in this post. I had forgotten in that stage to include the event. In fact I originally passed 'event' as just 'e' and I left it out of this post as a mistake. I'll leave it that way for others who may be making the same mistake. I was not getting any errors and "hi there" would console log just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is how you're using jQuery's `.next()` and `.find()`. Since `$(this)` is the `<a> tag`, [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/), which selects the next sibling, is the `<p> tag`. Then calling [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the `<p> tag` would check through all its descendants, for which there are none.

Therefore you need to select the parent of both the 'card-top' and 'card-bottom' divs before you traverse down with .find().

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mobile-icon').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.card-bottom').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

The first call to .parent() will be the parent of the `<a>` tag, which is the `'card-top' div`, and the .parent() of that will be the `'card' div`. Then calling `.find()` will work.

http://www.bootply.com/UMwXaOILHv

Comment: This is a great explanation. I really appreciate the answer, and I wasn't sure if I did .parent().parent() it would go back twice. As a designer primarily this makes a lot of sense to me because it's like I am going back two layers. I chose yours as the answer because you did a fine job explaining it, without being too technical. Thank you.

Comment: my pleasure :).

Answer (score 0):

1. Missing the closing `"` on `class="card>`
2. Add `event` to `function()` so it's `function(event)`
3. If you don't need to link anywhere use a `div` instead of an `a` tag and you won't need `preventDefault`.

```js
$('.mobile-icon').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.card').find('.card-bottom').slideToggle();
  // .closest finds the nearest .card ancestor (it goes up)
  // .find then finds .card-bottom within the closest .card
 });
```

```css
.mobile-icon {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px; height: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- FIRST CARD -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-top">
    <h1 class="card-title">Headline</h1>
    <div class="mobile-icon">click me</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
 </div>
 <!-- END CARD-TOP -->
   <div class="card-bottom">
     <p>Content to be toggled</p>
   </div>
   <!-- END CARD BOTTOM -->
</div>
<!-- END CARD -->

<!-- SECOND CARD -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-top">
    <h1 class="card-title">Headline</h1>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-icon">click me</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
 </div>
 <!-- END CARD-TOP -->
   <div class="card-bottom">
     <p>Content to be toggled</p>
   </div>
   <!-- END CARD BOTTOM -->
</div>
<!-- END CARD -->
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/m2zaLfnz/

Comment: This is a great solution and this works really well. The missing " in the class .card was a silly mistake as I was deleting unnecessary classes from the actual code I am using. I have edited my original post to include it. Thanks so much for your answer. I chose another because it was explained how it was traversing the DOM in a way I can comprehend. Thank you for your help!